# C# Compare and find differences in an array/list of custom class objects quickly

Tags: c#, arrays

I sure hope this is not a duplicate question, but I sure couldn't find one if there is another out there.

I have a client that stores a large subset of data in a custom class. Lets call the class "Site" for the purpose of this question.

Each "Site" has dozens of properties, but the key properties are Type (string 2-3 chars long), and "Index" which is a integer. Each site is identified by its Type then Index. Index alone is not unique for each Site.

There are times when I need to quickly find the differences between 2 Arrays (Generic List) of Site objects. For instance, I may need to extract all items that are in Array 1 but not in Array 2.

The way we do that now is with multiple Foreach loops.. the problem with that is its insanely slow once the array of sites is over 5000... and we need to make sure its efficient with up to 100,000 sites.

Can someone please give me a kick in the right direction here? What I'm looking for exactly is a fast way to get a list of sites that are in array 1 but not array 2, or vice versa. Simple really, but its the speed thats at issue :)

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Show your code so far please.

Comment: can you use Linq? you could probably achieve this with join.

Comment: why don't you use databases? SQL CE is for local use.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Linq. I see a suggestion below for that as well. I will take the next hour to research and try that... then post here if that does not work out.

Comment: The database is WAY too slow. We must use SQLite... I am not a fan of SQLite, but it is what we have to work with for other technical reasons... so we read the data in to memory on application start and use a List<> of objects for local manipulation, saving to the database only when something changes.

Comment: Why would Linq be faster?

Comment: then  by your question type is unique?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you can use Linq for this.

```
string[] uniqueSites = sites1.Union(sites2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This will give you unique values between the 2 arrays and avoid duplicates.

Comment: would it be faster to distinct both lists to avoid processing duplicates?

Comment: To be complete answer please make sure to briefly discuss `GetHashCode` / comparers.

Comment: Why would this be faster than simple for each's? The question is about getting a *better performance*, not *how* to do it in the first place.

Comment: I do not know Linq, and while your sample there would not work simply because there are no "2" fields that can be compared, it is possible Linq will allow multiple field comparisons. I will do some research on that now... might be a good chance to learn a new language :)

Comment: Depends on how hes doing it now. Since he didn't show code I don't know if this is faster or not. Linq brings overhead so it may or may not be faster then what he is doing now.

Comment: @Dom There are no duplicates, but the objects do not have a single ID column. As stated, each instance of "Type" + "Index" is unique in each of the lists, but neither the type nor index are unique in and of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be with hash sets: create a hash set of "site keys" - pairs of `{type, index}`, go through the sites in the first list, add keys to a hash set, then go through the second list, and determine the membership by checking if the corresponding key is present in the hash set.

Here is a skeletal implementation:

```
IList<Site> listA = ...
IList<Site> listB = ...
var keysA = new HashSet<Tuple<string,int>>(
    listA.Select(site => Tuple.Create(site.Type, site.Index))
);
foreach (var site in listB) {
    var keyB = Tuple.Create(site.Type, site.Index);
    if (keysA.Contains(keyB)) {
        // site is in both lists
    } else {
        // site is in listB but not listA
    }
}
```

I used built-in type `Tuple<T1,T2>` to represent "site keys" - pairs of a `string` and an `int`, where the `string` is site's type, and `int` is site's index. You can use your own type, or even use the `Site` itself with an appropriate override of `GetHashCode`/`Equals` or an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Site>`.

Comment: thats a very good idea... I would never have thought of that, and it won't take too long to implement and test. I will give it a go and see how the speed compares. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> There are times when I need to quickly find the differences between 2 Arrays (Generic List) of Site objects. For instance, I may need to extract all items that are in Array 1 but not in Array 2.

You can use LINQ for this. To test Type and Index, you'll need to either override GetHashCode/Equals, or create a custom equality comparer. Piece of cake.

```
IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = ...;
var values = array1.Except(array2, comparer);
```